# Connected App not working for few Salesforce org only- Oauth Login

Tags: java, oauth, salesforce

I have created an application to login into any salesforce account using oAuth Rest api JAVA.
This works fine with few org but does not allow all. 
Below are the two endpoints used in this process :

**Step 1 :**

```
String url = "https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize";
String body = "response_type=code&client_id="+customerKey+"&redirect_uri="+URLEncoder.encode("url", "UTF-8")";
```

**Step 2 :**

```
String url2 = "https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token";
String body2 = "response_type=code&grant_type=authorization_code&code="+code+"&client_id="+customerKey+"&client_secret="+secret+"&redirect_uri="+URLEncoder.encode("url", "UTF-8");
```

I have Developer Edition org. Above code works for 2 different org. But doesnot work in every case.
Am I missing something ?

Comment: Any chance the orgs that aren't working have "My Domain" enabled or are within the Government Cloud (the org is on NA21).

Comment: @RobDavis No,  MyDomain is not enabled for those org. How can I check if it is within government cloud ?